# Define a unique primary key based on 2 columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I would like to define a unique key for records based on 2 columns : 'id' and 'language'

to let the user submits the following strings :
 id=1  language=en  value=blabla english
 id=1  language=fr  value=blabla french

I tried to use set_primary_key and also add_index but it didn't work ( add_index :words, ["id", "language_id"], :unique => true )

I have the following model :

```ruby
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dictionnary
  belongs_to :language

  attr_accessible :lang, :rev, :value, :dictionnary_id, :language_id

  validates :value, :uniqueness => true

end
```

and this

```ruby
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :words

    attr_accessible :lang
end
```

Comment: if the word belongs to a Language why do you need to store the lang with it?  You can just delegate it to the Language Model.  That being said you will be fighting rails.  I would just use the ID key as the primary key. delegate :lang to Language and not worry about the composite key

Comment: indeed, thanks. :lang is coming from ald scaffilding. I need to remove it from here since I use the Language model. Thx

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`add_index :words, ["id", "language_id"], :unique => true`

It should work. Maybe you have already some non-unique data in your db and index can't be created? But (as @Doon noticed it will be redundant since id is always unique). So you need create primary key on two columns.

To define 2 column primary key in rails use:

```
create_table :words, {:id => false} do |t|
  t.integer :id
  t.integer :language_id
  t.string :value
  t.timestamps
end
execute "ALTER TABLE words ADD PRIMARY KEY (id,language_id);"
```

And set primary_key in your model with this gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/composite_primary_keys:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_keys = :id,:language_id
end
```

Comment: this will add unique index on the table for id/language_id) but more than likely id will still be the primary key, and subject to unique index. so this index would be redundant since id is always unique.

Comment: Also possible: `validates :language_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:id] }`

Comment: How to create a combined unique (not primary) key based on two columns? Which basically prevents creation of multiple rows having the same values on column a & column b ..

Comment: Just wanted to add that one can also add a composite_primary_key and provide a name for that constraint with the following command:
`execute "ALTER TABLE words ADD CONSTRAINT contraint_name PRIMARY KEY (id, language_id)"`

Comment: should be `self.primary_key` (singular form) instead of `self.primary_keys`

Answer (score 10):

In Rails 5 you can do the following:

```
create_table :words, primary_key: %i[id language_id] do |t|
  t.integer :id
  t.integer :language_id
  t.string :value
  t.timestamps
end
```

It is also NOT necessary to set the `primary_key` attribute on the `Word` model.

Comment: Rails 5 [still does not support composite primary keys](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e00b467c479e495292095e09ce53b326035ec467/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb#L131)

Answer (score 3):

**Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  self.primary_keys = :name
end
```

**Migration**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :emailid
      t.string :password_digest
      t.integer :locked, :default => 0
      t.text :secretquestion
      t.string :answer

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :users, :name, :unique => true
  end
end
```

You will get this table

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comments you will be fighting rails if you try this, and it isn't really supported out of the box.  you can look at http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org  which offers a way to do composite primary keys in rails. I haven't used it, as I haven't had a need yet (normally when I have something that is composite key like it is just a join table with no primary key and a unique index on the joined pair  (HABTM).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case you might want to try out [composite key gem](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/) which allows you to define composite primary keys and also ehances ActiveRecord to deal with this kind of model (helps a lot for associations to this model or for url_for helpers etc.).

So if you plan in using this model as any other rails model the gem will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when migrating a site to Rails. I had a table which stores text data for each language my site is available in so I had something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Project_Lang(
    project_id INT NOT NULL,
    language_id INT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(80),
    description TEXT,

    PRIMARY KEY pk_Project_Lang(project_id, language_id),

    FOREIGN KEY fk_Project_Lang_Project(project_id)
        REFERENCES Project(project_id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY fk_Project_Lang_Language(language_id)
        REFERENCES Language(language_id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE = utf8_spanish_ci;
```

But since Rails doesn't handle composite primary keys out of the box I was forced to change the structure of the table so it had it's own primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE Project_Lang(
    project_lang_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    project_id INT NOT NULL,
    language_id INT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(80),
    description TEXT,

    UNIQUE INDEX(project_id, language_id),

    FOREIGN KEY fk_Project_Lang_Project(project_id)
        REFERENCES Project(project_id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY fk_Project_Lang_Language(language_id)
        REFERENCES Language(language_id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE = utf8_spanish_ci;
```

I also created a unique index for the columns that previously made the composite primary key so that no duplicate record is inserted. Then in my Rails model I could simply:

```
self.primary_key = "project_lang_id"
```

And that did the trick. Is not what I wanted but is better than fighting the framework.