# Two columns in Rails foreign key migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

Regards!

I can add foreign key to table in Rails migration on this way:

```
add_foreign_key :teachers, :departamentos, name: "teachers_departamento_id", 
column: :codigo_departamento, primary_key: :codigo
```

But, How do I add two columns into foreign key?

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain what functionality you want to achieve by doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like

```
add_index :table, ["column1", "column2"], :unique => true
```

based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746280/define-a-unique-primary-key-based-on-2-columns) from SO

Comment: Thanks by answering. That add index only but don't add the foreign key.